# Meteor Admin login not retriving all records from mongodb

Tags: meteor

I am working on a project using meteor(0.8.2) and it has got a login component. Every user gets to see his data when user logs in. I am creating a admin login where, admin should able to see the data of all users. Any ideas on this?

My js code:

```
//retrieving records according to userid
Template.entries.entries = function () {
        // return all entries sorted by time
        return addressDB.find({userId: Meteor.userId()}, { sort: { time: -1 }});
    }
```

another snippet of js code,

```
//this code inserts the data in collection

var user = Meteor.user();
     var userId= Meteor.userId();
             if (!user) {
                 return;
             }
             if(!userId){return;}
     console.log("new user created by the meteor user function ");
     addressDB.insert({
      userId:userId,
      user:user,
     innovationCenter:innovation_center_name,
     description:description,
     address:temp});
     console.log("data inserted");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can yse [roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/) to simply manage you users privileges. Then, in you publish function (on server):

```
Meteor.publish('addresses', function () {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin') {
    return addressDB.find({});
  } else {
    return addressDB.find({userId: Meteor.userId()});
  }
});
```

Please remember to remove `autopublish` package and subscribe to `addresses` data stream on client side with

```
Meteor.subscribe('addresses');
```